# How can I provide a compile-time guarantee that my method will return the same object it gets in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, this, path-dependent-type

In a Scala class, I can conveniently declare the return type of a method to be `this.type` to guarantee that it will return the same object it is called on:

```
class Foo {
  def bar: this.type = this
}
```

Is there a way I can similarly specify that a method that accepts a given `AnyRef` param will return that reference exactly? The following snippet does not provide this guarantee, I could return any instance of `A`:

```
def processAndReturn[A <: AnyRef](obj: A): A = {
  // work with obj
  obj
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

huitseeker's suggestion is actually valid with the `-Ydependent-method-types` option:

```
$ scala -Ydependent-method-types
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).

scala>   def processAndReturn[A <: AnyRef](obj: A): obj.type = {
     |       // work with obj
     |       obj
     |   }
processAndReturn: [A <: AnyRef](obj: A)obj.type

scala> processAndReturn("hi")
res1: java.lang.String = hi
```

From [this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3621), I gather that experimental dependent method types have been around for a while, and there's even a published paper using them, but the implementation may be buggy. There has been some discussion about reworking Scala's type system foundations (see Adriaan Moor's [slides](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/8gWgzVY-Zd0/1m5VL26QZ6sJ) on Dependent Object Types). If it works out, I imagine that dependent method types (among other things) will be completely kosher in future versions of Scala.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you would want to give the return type `obj.type` in your method above, but this is unfortunately prohibited as of now. As per [the spec, p.47](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=47):

> (...) at present singleton types of method parameters may only appear in the method
>   body; so dependent method types are not supported.

There may be some way to achieve what you want, but not in the type specification of that method by itself.

Answer (score 1):

huitseeker and Kipton probably have the direct answer you're looking for.

With that said, the only use case I can imagine is if you want to chain calls on the same object and ensure you're really working on the same object. Are there other?

For instance:

```
class Counter {
  var i = 0
  override def toString = i.toString
}

def incr(c: Counter): Counter = { c.i += 1; c }

val two = incr(incr((new Counter)))
// two: Counter = 2
```

If I call `incr` twice in a row, I expect to get two. Now let's imagine I am working with an ill-behaved function like:

```
def incorrect_incr(c: Counter): Counter = { 
  c.i += 1
  new Counter // should return c but does not
}

val notTwo = incorrect_incr(incorrect_incr(new Counter))
// notTwo: Counter = 0
```

I think using a wrapper to ensure we keep working on the same object would solve this problem (edited after thinking on how to make this more idiomatic):

```
case class Id[T <: AnyRef](t:T) {
  def map[U](f: (T) => U): Id[T] = { 
    f(t)
    this
  }
  def get: T = t
}

val reallyTwo = Id(new Counter).map(incorrect_incr).map(incorrect_incr).get
// reallyTwo: Counter = 2
```

`map` basically ensures the function is called for its side effect, `get` unwraps the value...

Comment: Another valid use case I can imagine is emulating a method returning `this.type` with the pimp-my-library pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: if you're going to return what you passed in, why not just use void? After all, you already have the object in the calling code, don't you?

Comment: Maybe, but that isn't really the point; I'm interested in the typesystem and the compile-time guarantees it can or cannot provide. `this.type` for instance is very convenient for chaining method calls on the same object.